# how to use SWIGTYPE_p_CHAR class in my main class?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I have used typemaps :

```
%include "typemaps.i"

%apply SWIGTYPE * {char *deci};
```

This is the proxy class generated by SWIG:

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_char {
    private long swigCPtr;

    protected SWIGTYPE_p_char(long cPtr, boolean futureUse) {
        swigCPtr = cPtr;
    }

    protected SWIGTYPE_p_char() {
        swigCPtr = 0;
    }

    protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_char obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why aren't you using the default string typemaps? Can you show a *minimal* function that shows how you might want to use this? I think you're over complicating stuff. Even if you aren't there's probably a nicer way to wrap it for Java users.

Comment: @Flexo I got it... thanks a lot for your response!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems trivial, but have you tried:

```
SWIGTYPE_p_char my_p_char;
```

after all, all that the class contains is a long int representation of the pointer address

clearly you can only use this for a c function that returns a char* or uses a char* parameter as a pseudo return value

if you want to use a char* input parameter then you'll most likely have to write a helper function of some sort

I wrapped this function prototype with SWIG recently:

```
int load_config(const char *fn, Config *cfg);
```

which loaded data into my Config data-structure from a file specified by a string (char*)

I was able to call it from Java with the following line:

```
example.load_config("test.cfg", cfg);
```

or alternatively:

```
String cfg_file = "test.cfg";
example.load_config(cfg_file, cfg);
```

Comment: Yeah i have tried that!! but my problem is how to intialize that variable my_P_char??? and in that class i dont have getters or setters... just some function to get "getPtr"

Comment: I don't think you can without a helper function of some sort, e.g. getter and setter functions, as Java has no concept of a pointer - maybe post some code snippets showing what your trying to do, e.g. function prototypes, some of your java code etc.

Comment: i mean the C funtion prototypes your trying to call from Java not the auto-generated SWIG stuff - have you had a close read of http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#tips_techniques

Comment: yeah i have read that!!! but im trying to create an object of the above SWIG generated class... Also once i intialize that variable then i can call my function like this :void Example.decimal(my_p_char)

Comment: have added to my post showing how I managed to pass in data to a char* parameter for a wrapped C function